# File permissions on files created by PHP

Tags: php, nginx, cron, file-permissions, background-process

In my Debian Stretch docker container, I am creating and updating files with PHP and getting permission errors because HTTP and background processes are different users.

When the files are created/updated via the web server they are owned by `nginx:nginx`. When they are updated via a background process such as cron or Supervisor, they are changed to `root:root`.

I'm not sure how to fix this so the folder that stores the setting files `/var/www/html/settings` works with both?

Comment: cron: https://superuser.com/questions/170866/how-to-run-a-cron-job-as-a-specific-user
supervisor: https://serverfault.com/questions/529658/how-can-i-have-supervisor-running-my-programs-as-another-user

Comment: Have your cron execute under the `nginx` user instead. The duplicate shows how to do that